# What should I take into consideration when choosing a new antenna?

Tags: antenna, hackrf

I am trying to choose a new antenna for the HackRf One, but there are several variables to consider, such as the frequency, threading, resistance etc. In general, what things should I take into account when choosing a new antenna to ensure compatibility.

Comment: sorry, this is too broad. What's the thing you want to do with that antenna? You wouldn't walk into a tool shop and ask "what to consider when buying a new *tool*", because you'd precisely know what the answer would be: *Ask yourself what you need that tool for*. Some people need a hammer. Some people need a saw. The criteria for these people are very different.

Comment: What's wrong with your old antenna? I guess that would have to be your primary consideration.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I'm looking for a 1-2 mi. range, omnidirectional, 2.4Ghz antenna, to use with the HackRf One that will be used to create a TDOA system, but maybe more precisely, I am mostly concerned with figuring out what is required to ensure basic compatibility with the HackRf One i.e. it won't catch fire, it'll screw in etc.

Comment: This all should be part of your question. You already got an answer to your previous question that explains compatibility: The only thing you need to care about is 50Ω impedance, full stop.